# C++ STL string erase

Tags: c++, string, stl, runtime-error

I have made a small program which remove words from a sentence. Everytime I try to run the program, it give me these error

> Error 2   error C2040: '==' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection
>   from 'const char [4]' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   12.0\vc\include\xutility  line:3026   column:1    STL string erase

and

> Error 1   error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'const char *' to
>   'int' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   12.0\vc\include\xutility  line:3026   column:1    STL string erase

also here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string sample("hello world");
    cout << "The sample string is: ";
    cout << sample << endl;
    //erasing world
    cout << "Erasing world" << endl;
    sample.erase(5, 10);
    cout << sample << endl;
    //finding h and erasing it
    string::iterator iCharH = std::string::find(sample.begin(), sample.end(), "h");
    cout << "finding h and erasing it" << endl;
    if (iCharH != sample.end()){
        sample.erase(iCharH);
    }
    cout << sample << endl;
    //erasing entirely
    sample.erase(sample.begin(), sample.end());
    if (sample.length() == 0){
        cout << "The string is empty" << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please give line numbers with your error messages.

Comment: `std::find` only finds a single element (i.e., a character), not a subset (i.e., a substring). Use `std::string::find`.

Comment: Go to this reference: [std::basic_string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) for the details on the four overloaded versions of the `std::string::find` member function.  Use this one for the three different erase overloads: [std::basic_string::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase).

Comment: Replace `"h"` in `string::iterator iCharH = std::string::find(sample.begin(), sample.end(), "h");`  with `'h'`

Answer (score 0):

What you need - as written by chris in the comment - is [std::string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/). The reason is basically that you wish to remove words, and not single characters.

Comment: A high reputation member (e.g. 100K+) has informed me on an answer I posted over 30 days ago that the above web site is less preferred than `cppreference.com`.  Unfortunately, that is the only comment I have from the high reputation member.  I do not have any concrete reasons for avoiding the listed site.

Comment: I did try that but it give me an error.                          Error 1 error C2665: 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::find' : none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types line:15 column:1 STL string erase

Comment: @Jim What are the exact implementation coding used for both reworked `words.find(...)` and `words.erase(...)` function calls?

Comment: @CPlusPlusOOAandD I have made changes to my post and this is the reworked coding of the previous one

Comment: @Jim I have posted an answer that should clarify, along with repeating the handy online C++ reference pages.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misunderstanding of the `std::string::erase` and `std::string::find` member functions.  Have the references listed in my comment above been helpful, repeated here for clarity: [std::basic_string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [std::basic_string::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase)?

Use these three to four modifications and it should resolve the issues.  Note that all code from the post above is repeated with modifications and extra comments, for having all of it in one location for future review.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string sample("hello world");
    cout << "The sample string is: ";
    cout << sample << endl;
    //erasing world
    cout << "Erasing world" << endl;

    //
    // Erase the word "world" from the string, while not sending erase more
    // characters to erase than going past the end of the string.
    // erase is friendly enough not to have issues with passing a higher count
    // in the second parameter, but future C++ versions could throw an exception
    // in some future standard, e.g. C++14 or later.
    //
    sample.erase(5, 6);
    cout << sample << endl;

    //finding h and erasing it
    //
    // Use the short version of the find member function to look for the string
    // "h".  iCharH is now declared as in int, instead of an iterator.  If the 
    // search string is not present, the iCharH value will be std::string::npos,
    // otherwise iCharH will contain the starting index position of the search
    // string.
    //    string::iterator iCharH = std::string::find(sample.begin(), sample.end(), "h");
    //
    int iCharH = sample.find("h");
    cout << "finding h and erasing it" << endl;

    //
    // Using a different overloaded form of erase, make sure to remove the 
    // exact number of characters.  In this case, the number is ONE.  The
    // std::string::npos can be shortened to string::npos, but only because
    // using namespace std; is above.
    //
    if (iCharH != std::string::npos){
        sample.erase(iCharH, 1);
    }
    cout << sample << endl;
    //erasing entirely

    //
    // Passing no parameters to erase empties a string.  This is optional, but
    // less typing than the iterator version.  The iterator version works 
    // perfectly too.
    //    sample.erase(sample.begin(), sample.end());
    //
    sample.erase();
    if (sample.length() == 0){
        cout << "The string is empty" << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```